# Add list data into Excel with Python

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I have a file with the following format:

```
2015-11-01|00:00:00|1
2015-11-02|23:00:00|11
2015-11-03|07:00:00|12
2015-11-04|09:00:00|20
```

I'd like to be able to convert these lines into list format so I can execute the fields like below:

```
for date, hour, count in arr:
       incoming_images.write(row, col, date)
       incoming_images.write(row, col + 1, hour)
       incoming_images.write(row, col + 2, count)
       row +=1
```

I need help figuring out how to create this "arr" (if possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Str = open("file").read()
lines =Str.count('\n')
Str= Str.replace('\n', '|')
words = Str.split("|")
for i in range(0,len(words)-1,3)
   date.append(words[i])
   hour.append(words[i+1])
   count.append(words[i+2])

for date, hour, count in zip(date,hour,count):
   incoming_images.write(row, col, date)
   incoming_images.write(row, col + 1, hour)
   incoming_images.write(row, col + 2, count)
   row +=1
```

Comment: File "sql_test.py", line 29, in <module>
    date.append(words[i])
NameError: name 'date' is not defined

Comment: And where is zip defined?

Comment: Are u in python 2.x or 3.x

Comment: I'm in Python 2.7. I assigned array variables for date, hour and count, but the output is not correct. It's putting the hour, the count and then the date. It is also deleting the last piece of date data.

Comment: For zip "import itertool"

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sql_test.py", line 37, in <module>
    hour.append(words[i+1])
IndexError: list index out of range -- it looks like there is an extra blank space being appended to words

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94881/discussion-between-user3299633-and-ravichandra).

Comment: In range use 'len(words)-1'

Comment: New error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sql_test.py", line 38, in <module>
    for i in range(0,len(words-1),3):
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'int'